# If $x, x' \in C$ then prove that $C_x =C_{x'}$ where C is a closed convex set

Tags: convex-analysis

This question was part of my analysis quiz( now over) and I was unable to solve it. So, I am posting it here.

> Let C be a closed convex set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.For any $x\in C$, define $C_x =$  {$y \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x+ty \in C$ for all $t\geq 0$}.

Prove that  for any two points $x, x' \in C$ we have $C_x = C_{x'}$

The problem is that I am not able to think which result I should use and I am completely struck on the problem. I think it even after the quiz but still couldn't make any progress.

I have been following Tom M Apostol. Can you please give some hints?

Comment: Hint: For every $y \in C_x$ consider the set $S := \{sx+(1-s)x'+ty \in \mathbb{R}^2: s \in (0,1), t \geq 0\}.$ Is $S \subseteq C$?

Comment: General hint: draw figures for your own sake!